# Compare two strings with the is-operator

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I just realized that you can compare two strings with `is`

So something like `bool areEqual = "" is "";` returns `true` or also

```
string x = null;
bool areEqual = x is null;
```

I didn't know this is possible and didn't find any resources on the web. 
Are there any benefits using the `is` operator over `Equals` or `==` ?

Comment: `bool isString = x is string;` use `is` for type comparison

Comment: `is` operator checks for type equality. Since both empty strings have same `string` type, the operation will return `true`.

Comment: I'm not talking about comparing the type.  `"" is "x"` returns `False` - so your comment is wrong @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: You can only compare strings with constants using the `is` pattern, as far as I know there are no benefits in doing so over using `==`. For other types, that implement equality operators, there is a benefit in using `x is null`, as this pattern will not use the equality operator and only do a null-reference check.

Comment: All of you posting comments about `is` is only for type checking need to read up on pattern matching in C# 7.

Comment: and strangely : `if(x is null)` does not gives meaningful build error, one of my colleague had hard time why it's not building and then i pointed out his null comparison was wrong

Comment: `x is null` requires C# 7 and above. `if (x is null)` is not wrong *if you're using C# 7 or above*.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ahhh thats why I couldnt find it. New language feature in C# 7 and I didn't know what it's called... for null checking on strings that's pretty cool...

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o28vMb), which shows that the `==` operator is only called once, and not for `is`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it was in C# 6 specific

Comment: Apparently in the end they work the same, at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare a string *and a constant* using the `is` *pattern*, which is new in C# 7.

The most common usage of this pattern will be to do null-checks, without invoking the equality operator.

Take this example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();

        Console.WriteLine(test == null);
        Console.WriteLine(test is null);
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static bool operator ==(Test a, Test b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==");
            return ReferenceEquals(a, b);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Test a, Test b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!=");
            return !ReferenceEquals(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
==
False
False
```

meaning, the `==` operator, comparing a `Test` and a constant, will only be invoked once. When using `is`, it won't be. This is handy for checking against `null` without using `ReferenceEquals` (though `ReferenceEquals` is in fact special-handled by the compiler). (see further below for more information).

For strings, however, it has very little benefit as the compiler already does a lot of magic rewriting for you.

If you use a string instead of the type from my example above, the `ceq` instruction which is a direct comparison will be done in both cases, even if string has overloaded the `==` operator.

**Edit:** As was pointed by [@meJustAndrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6357360/mejustandrew) in the comments, this is because the comparison is done on the reference as though it was of type `object`, and thus no operators are involved. You can see from his answer here, near the bottom, what is actually happening. The generated code of `test is null` is identical to the one from `(object)test == null`.

---

This particular conversion only holds true for reference types, however.

If the code in `Main` above had been

```
var test = (int?)10;

Console.WriteLine(test == null);
Console.WriteLine(test is null);
```

both would compile to this equivalent code:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.HasValue == false);
```

However, this is just another area where there's a lot of compiler magic involved.

Comment: It indeed seems that the `==` operator will be invoked once for the classic null check and not at all for the `is null` check, but it actually is invoked in both cases.

Comment: It seems not, as is evident by the code not outputting `==` more than once.

Comment: And see this: https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/using-is-instead-of-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-null-reference

Comment: Have you seen my answer below?

Comment: `is` just calls the `==` on the `object` type instead of your custom type, this is why you don't see its output in the console. Please at least update your answer not to mislead any further readers.

Comment: `is null` is compiler magic, it depends on the situation, there is no simple rewrite that just casts to `object` and then does a normal comparison, as this would add a boxing operation when using the `is null` pattern for nullable value types. In other words, this: `x is null` is not *always* rewritten as `(object)x == null`. In other words, for reference types you're right but it is not as simple as that on the compiler level either.

Answer (score 1):

`is` is usually used for type checking as many have already pointed out in the comments.

For example:

```
object obj = 23;
bool isInt = obj is int; //this will be true
```

You can of course use it to compare strings or against null, but (and this is going slightly to primary opinion based answer) I would advice against it, because it won't be consistent with most of the projects where you will see string comparisons or null checks.

For example, a null check would be `if(a != null)` or `if(a is null)` which will drive people to use comparisons in two different ways.

**EDIT:**

I have just written a small piece of code in order to see what happens behind the scenes and it seems that it is no difference between using the `is` operator and classic null checks. For the following code:

```
object obj = 23;

bool withIs = obj is null;
bool withEquals = obj == null;
```

The disassembled version from the IL looks like this:

```
object obj = 23;
bool withIs = obj == null;
bool withEquals = obj == null;
```

So it turns out that the generated IL is the same in the end which once again makes me advise you to use the `is` operator only for type checks.

For the code which is used in the other answer, this is how the `Main` function looks like in the IL:

```
    Test test = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(test == null);
    Console.WriteLine((object)test == null);
```

You can see that on the last line the `test` variable has a cast to an `object` and this is why for the `is null` comparison, the `==` operator seems to not be invoked.